Fetch large files from managed node in Ansible
I am running into the limitations of the Ansible fetch module. Trying to get a somewhat big file - between 1MB and 250MB - which is chearly too much for fetch.
- name: get result files back
  fetch:
    src: /tmp/file_generated_previous_step.tar.gz
    dest: file_generated_{{ inventory_hostname }}.tar.gz
    flat: yes

This works when the file is small, but gives a pretty long error when the file is about 1-2MB.
My workaround is to use scp on the file from the controller, like this:
- name: get result files back
  shell: ' scp {{ inventory_hostname }}:/tmp/file_generated_previous_step.tar.gz file_generated_{{ inventory_hostname }}.tar.gz'
  delegate_to: localhost

This is working when I have public key authentication with no password to the host, but has no error handling, whatsoever.
So, my question is: is there a correct method to achieve the same result?
With the constraint that I am under Ansible 2.4.

Ansible 2.4 has been out of support for an eternity (since 2018!). Upgrade.

Wouldn't be the synchronize module a better option?

@β.εηοιτ.βε long story short: upgrade is not an option here. Not my decision though.

@U880D Thanks a lot! That is the solution I longed for!

Try to use synchronize. It uses rsync and can handle big files with no problem.
Most people missed that it can handle both directions, including from servers to controller:
mode:

Specify the direction of the synchronization.

In push mode the localhost or delegate is the source.

In pull mode the remote host in context is the source.

Choices:

    "pull"

    "push" ← (default)

